# Server chooser and SSH launcher with GUI

Tags: linux, gui, ssh

Is there a piece of software available for Linux that is a type of "system chooser?"

That is, I want to define a set of hostnames and user accounts, and be able to group them, and have software present me with a GUI for "selecting" one of these hosts whereby when I click on one, the action is to launch an SSH terminal to that target.

Bonus feature would be an omnibar-style search function.

I don't want anything that needs to run a process on the target hosts. PuTTY lets you set up a list of hosts, but doesn't allow you to organize them in any way.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

Termius (https://www.termius.com/) seems to have these features. It’s cross-platform. It does have some paid features, but the features you describe should be free.

Answer (score 0):

[Cockpit](http://cockpit-project.org/) might be able to do that.

[PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) can run on Linux and it has some sort of chooser.

But not sure if it fits your needs. They seem really wide from your description.